# Cant Print Int after varchar

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Why can't I print my `DeptID` which is an integer?

```
Alter proc spGetNameByID
    @ID int,
    @Name varchar(50) output,
    @Gender varchar (50) output,
    @DeptID int output
as
begin
    Select 
        @Name = Name, @Gender = Gender , 
        @DeptID = DeptID 
    from 
        tblEmployee 
    where 
        ID = @ID
end

Declare @GetName varchar(50), @GetGender varchar(50), @GetDeptID int

Execute spGetNameByID 1, @GetName out, @GetGender out, @GetDeptID out

Print 'Name of Employee is ' + @GetName + ' Gender is ' + @GetGender + 'Dept ID is ' + @GetDeptID
```

My error is

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Name of Employee is John Gender is MaleDept ID is ' to data type int.

Answer (score 4):

The `@GetDeptID` is an Integer value, you need to convert it to varchar before concatenating it to a string

```
Print 'Name of Employee is ' + @GetName + ' Gender is ' 
                  + @GetGender + 'Dept ID is ' + CAST(@GetDeptID AS VARCHAR(10))
```

### Reason

When you do not explicitly convert the `Int` value to varchar before concatenating ,   `INT` being the higher prescience data type, SQL Server tries to convert your string into `INT` and fails, hence the error message.

Comment: Procedure or function spGetNameByID has too many arguments specified.

Comment: You are passing more parameters than the procedure is expecting, You should pass no more than 4 parameters to your procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using RAISERROR with a severity of zero.  This will provide similar functionality as `PRINT` plus allow you to use substitution parameters.

```
RAISERROR('Name of Employee is %s Gender is %s Dept ID is %d', 0, 0, @GetName, @GetGender, @GetDeptID);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert Numerical values to String because print can only understand the unique value by type as an argument.

```
Print 'Name of Employee is ' + @GetName + ' Gender is ' + @GetGender + 'Dept ID is ' + Convert(varchar(18), @GetDeptID)
```